# Missing functions in Karma tests

Tags: javascript, karma-runner

I'm using Jasmine, Karma, and PhantomJS to automate my tests, but I'm hitting a problem: Phantom doesn't seem to parse my JS correctly. For example, I'm using this mock:

```
var App = function() {
  return {
    pageController : {
      currentPage : {
        on : function() {},
        toJSON : function() {},
        get : function() {
          return dark;
        }
      }
    },
    mainLayout : {
      header : {
        show : function() {},
        $el : {}
      }
    }
  };
};

console.log("in test", App());
```

...which logs out as:

```
PhantomJS 1.9 (Mac) LOG: [ 'in test',
  { pageController: {},
    mainLayout: { header: [Object] } } ]
```

app.pageController has been emptied here, which causes my tests to fail. Why is this happening & how I can fix it?

The problem seems directly related to the function definitions. For example:

```
console.log("this is a function:", function() { return 'wat'; });
```

yields

```
PhantomJS 1.9 (Mac) LOG: [ 'this is a function:', null ]
```

The error also occurs in Chrome. It squashes created jasmine spies as well, so I'm guessing it's to do with Karma?

Answer (score 1):

Karma's logging reports all functions as `null`. (Tests were failing for unrelated reasons).